# PHP preg_replace not replacing anything

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

Can someone tell me why when I run this code the preg_replace function seems like it does nothing?

```
<?php
    $string     = 'waka http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm waka';
    $search     = '#http\:\/\/.\.webm #';
    $replace    = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="$1" type="video/webm"></video>';
    $url = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
    echo $url;
?>
```

Is my $search string wrong? If so, how can I fix it? It's suppose to replace strings starting in `http://` and ending in `.webm` and surround them with the html code needed to play the .webm video.

Comment: You match only a single (literally) character between `http://` and `.webm`

Comment: Change `.` in the middle to `.+`: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/crO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this...

```
$string     = 'waka http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm waka';
$search     = '/(https?\:\/\/.+?\.webm)\h/';
$replace    = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="$1" type="video/webm"></video> ';
$url = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
waka <video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm"></video> waka
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/qR1xJ7/2

Comment: That worked perfectly. I wonder why .+? didn't work on mine though. Can you tell me what that \h does at the end? And why you have the ( and ) around the http and webm?

Comment: The `()` are so the value is captured without that it doesn't get saved to the `$1`. The `\h` matches a horizontal space, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out. I'm now using:

```
$search     = '#http:\/\/([^\']+)\.webm #';
```

Comment: I'd just do `.+?` instead of `[^']` (`any character until`, I think makes more sense then `not quote until` since there isn't a quote in your string). Since `#` are your delimiters you don't need to escape the `/`s.

Comment: When I use ".+?" it turns the url into "http://.webm" You're right about the # and not needing the \'s though. :D

Comment: It shouldn't, https://regex101.com/r/qR1xJ7/1. I didn't actually try in PHP yet but I've never had an issue with it in the past.